# Why does my AutoHotKey script not display any checkbox when I tell it to?

Tags: windows, scripting, autohotkey

This is my test.ahk:

```
InputBox, UserInput, Test, Insert some text:
Gui, Add, CheckBox, whatever, A checkbox text
```

In spite of the second line, it only display a GUI box with a text input field and the "Insert some text:" text -- there is no checkbox anywhere to be seen.

I've stared at and browsed around the manual for hours upon hours now but it just won't appear no matter what. This syntax is supposed to work: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControls.htm#Checkbox

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track! I'm sorry you had a frustrating experience trying to get it to work. You'll need one more line after your code:

```
Gui, Show
```

Note that "whatever" is an invalid option for the checkbox and you won't see it when GUI pops up due to that.

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#Show

Comment: Well, I added a "v" before the "whatever" as to make it correct. and then "Gui, Show" after the lines I had. Now, it opens the GUI with only the text field (no checkbox), and when you have submitted it, it displays a separate GUI window with just the checkbox!

Comment: Ah, I see. The `InputBox` command is totally separate from the GUI controls. It's sort of like a pre-built GUI with only a few options to control it. In your case, you'll need to abandon `InputBox` and use `Gui, Add, Edit, ...`, `Gui, Add, Text, ...`, and `Gui, Add, Button, ...` instead.